# SQL Insert Syntax

Tags: php, sql, insert

```
public $id;
public $post;
public $postedon;

public function insert($target_file){
    $sql="INSERT INTO post (ID,Post,PostedOn,Picture) VALUES (".$this->id.",".$this->post.",".$this->postedon.",".$target_file.")";
    $this->db->execute($sql);
}
```

//no error but i can't insert values on database

Comment: Post and postedon are strings no? You cannot insert as integer

Comment: Your forgot the `'` in the values.

Comment: No error? That's because there is no __error checking__. You have a solution to your syntax error, but your real problem is that you're not looking for errors and therefore have no way to diagnose them.

Comment: Use prepared statement. It is much more secure and readable.

Comment: Warning: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks,

Answer (score 2):

replace your query string with below code once

```
$sql="INSERT INTO post (ID,Post,PostedOn,Picture) VALUES ('$this->id','$this->post','$this->postedon','$target_file')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Tty to Use with `single quote` because you are inserting string value in database which need to `single quote` to insert in database.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO post (ID,Post,PostedOn,Picture) VALUES (".$this->id.",'".$this->post."','".$this->postedon."','".$target_file."')";
```

Instead Of

```
$sql="INSERT INTO post (ID,Post,PostedOn,Picture) VALUES (".$this->id.",".$this->post.",".$this->postedon.",".$target_file.")";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `'` in values

```
public $id;
public $post;
public $postedon;

public function insert($target_file){
    $sql="INSERT INTO post (ID,Post,PostedOn,Picture) VALUES (".$this->id.",'".$this->post."','".$this->postedon."','".$target_file."')";
    $this->db->execute($sql);
}
```

And you doing one risky thing, you are injecting values into string directly, it's not safe, someone can do sql injection, you can avoid this using param binding, read about sql injection.